# Submenu items not working anymore

Tags: menus, debug

Not sure where I am going wrong here... Submenu items in my website have stopped working across entire site with custom links/anchor tags.

Examples:
https://bell.works/new-jersey/on-the-block/
(Sub menu items under "On-The-Block": Eat, Play, Shop, Etc)

I can only get them to work one time when first accessing the site itself, but if i go to navigate through from "Eat" to "Shop" from the same page the event does not fire but shows item is linked.

Same applies to Work/Gather/Happenings/etc.

Thank you in advanced if taking the time to read this!

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Not spam. It is odd that I can only get them to work one time when first accessing the site itself, but if i go to navigate through from "Eat" to "Shop" from the same page the event does not fire

Comment: There you are. Sorry again for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Looks like you resolved this issue. Care to share what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, this is odd behavior.

I'm curious, what would happen if you added an anchor link directly on the 'On the Block' page (ie, #play)?

Not suggesting this as a solution, just trying to establish whether anchor links will work on the page if not included as part of the navigation.